# How to build a .jar library from intellij terminal by typing "ant"?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, ant, git-bash

I was able to generate a .jar file by just typing "ant" in the terminal on a mac that I was using. Now that I'm on my computer (windows) same project, same stuff, .xml file is done, but ant is not recognized neither by git-bash nor by intellij integrated terminal as a command.

I can create a .jar with another method, that's not the problem. The problem is that none of the terminals recognize "ant" commands. And I don't know how to create a .jar of a library that I want to use on another project...

I've tried:

- Following these instructions http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html to install ant but intellij already has ant and I'm able to build .xml with ant as well as create .jar by going through the project structure, artifacts, etc...
- Using git-bash, using powershell, using intellij terminal

Bash:

```
bash: ant: command not found
```

Intellij:

```
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm pretty new to all this so all the instructions and things I've tried are confusing. I'd like to type "ant" in the terminal and a .jar file would be created for me.

Comment: Add `ant/bin` directory to `PATH`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have a `%ANT_HOME%\bin;` but it's in a system variable called `Path` and not `PATH` dunno if that makes a difference.